# Why is Rabin Cryptosystem more secure than RSA?

Tags: cryptography

Why is Rabin Cryptosystem more secure than RSA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the wikipedia article on [Rabin cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem):

> ... the Rabin cryptosystem has the advantage that the problem on which it relies has been proved to be as hard as integer factorization, which is not currently known to be true of the RSA problem.

It's a matter of proof of whether RSA is indeed as hard as integer factorization or not. Rabin would potentially be more secure than RSA, if RSA is proved *not* to be as hard as int factorization.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia says:

The Rabin cryptosystem has the advantage that the problem on which it relies has been proved to be as hard as integer factorization, which is not currently known to be true of the RSA problem.

It's all down to math ;)